# Ajax is not working on first click on submit in contact form 7

Tags: ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a form created in contact form 7. But Ajax submission is not working on the first click of submit. On first click it leads to URL like https://example.com/resolution-table-reservation-management-system/#wpcf7-f651-o1 and when click second time on submit the ajax works. I have checked that my header and footer have wp_head() and wp_footer(); functions. and also checked after deactivating all the other plugins. But still ajax is not working. Is there any solution to this? Please help. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Are you using cache plugin?

Comment: Based on what you're showing as the URL, you have javascript disabled for contact form 7 submissions. https://contactform7.com/loading-javascript-and-stylesheet-only-when-it-is-necessary/

Comment: yes...thank you... i disabled the cache plugin and it fixed the issue.